# HP Smart Array P812 - Why is my Raid 60 gone?

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid6

I've got an HP ProLiant DL380 Gen7 with a Smart Array P812 which is connected to an MSA20 that houses 19 600GB drives.

After my VMs didn't boot up, I checked my array config and 2 drives failed:

```
=> ctrl slot=1 logicaldrive 1 show

Smart Array P812 in Slot 1

   array A

      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 7.6 TB
         Fault Tolerance: 60
         Number of Parity Groups: 2
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 1792 KB
         Status: Failed
         MultiDomain Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001CB429B3CE88E8CD6573D5
         Logical Drive Label: 025B181CPAGXQ0ARH0J02057B0
         Parity Group 0:
            physicaldrive 1E:1:1 (port 1E:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:2 (port 1E:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 0 MB, Failed)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:6 (port 1E:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:7 (port 1E:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 0 MB, Failed)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:8 (port 1E:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:9 (port 1E:box 1:bay 9, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:10 (port 1E:box 1:bay 10, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:11 (port 1E:box 1:bay 11, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:24 (port 1E:box 1:bay 24, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
         Parity Group 1:
            physicaldrive 1E:1:12 (port 1E:box 1:bay 12, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:13 (port 1E:box 1:bay 13, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:14 (port 1E:box 1:bay 14, SAS, 600 GB, Predictive Failure)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:15 (port 1E:box 1:bay 15, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:16 (port 1E:box 1:bay 16, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:17 (port 1E:box 1:bay 17, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:18 (port 1E:box 1:bay 18, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:19 (port 1E:box 1:bay 19, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
            physicaldrive 1E:1:20 (port 1E:box 1:bay 20, SAS, 600 GB, OK)
         Drive Type: Data
         LD Acceleration Method: Controller Cache
```

So out of my 19 Drives (18 + 1 Spare) 2 suddenly failed.

My understanding of RAID 60 is, that 2 drives per parity group may fail without losing data.

Can I somehow force the array to get online to copy the files to other drives?

Thanks for help in advance, I know my gear is ancient.

EDIT: It's an MSA70, not MSA20!

Comment: Power everything down. Power the MSA20 off. Let the drives spin down. Leave them off for a few minutes. Then power it all back on and closely monitor the system boot messages.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some drives in Parity Group 0 failed, and controller had started rebuild using the spare drive.
During the rebuild another drive (or drives) failed, seen that a few times.

It's hard to say precisely what happened if you do not have some logs or monitoring data (iow - if you looked at controller status only after boot problems).
You can look at 
ctrl slot=1 pd all show

Most likely you will see failed spare.
Most likely you won't be able to bring your data back without backups.